# SELECT list expression references column... which is neither grouped nor aggregated

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

To preface this, I have looked over similar topics and I do not believe it answers the problem that I face.

I am working with a SELECT statement that references 135 columns and it has been requested that this statement holds an aggregate function.

This errors as there is no GROUP BY clause at the end of the code.

The proposed solution was to GROUP BY - 1,2,3,4..133,134,135 [ommitiing the aggregated columns]. It also still seems to error.

This would make the code verbose and challenging to maintain. This leads me to believe there must be a more concise and maintainable solution.

Does anyone have any ideas on a better way to approach this? Possibly separating the aggregate measures into another table?

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps a correlated sub-query in the select list?

Comment: Thanks, Jarlh. Let me google that

Answer (score 0):

If you want aggregate measures on each row, then use window functions.  For instance:

```
select . . .,
       count(*) as total_rows,
       sum(amount) over (partition by ?) as total_amount_per_whatever
from . . .
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. I actually ended up separating the measure into another table as the statement was becoming far too complex. This is, however, something to keep in mind!